# Not able to create a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_counter
BEGIN 
 UPDATE bookmark bk,
 (SELECT count(Distinct user_bookmarks.user_id) AS bookmark_counter, bookmark_id 
  FROM user_bookmarks 
  LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON user_bookmarks.bookmark_id = bookmarks.id 
  GROUP BY user_bookmarks.bookmark_id 
 ) t
 set bk.counter = t.bookmark_counter
 where bk.id = t.bookmark_id
END //
```

But this is giving me an error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN  UPDATE bookmark bk, (SELECT count(Distinct user_bookmarks.user_id) AS' at line 2 Any idea? What is wrong here?

Comment: why do you flag it sql server if you have an error which says quite clearly mysql?

Comment: @Rigel1121: I see from some of your question edits that you're setting titles to title case - I think the community has decided that sentence case is preferred here. It's been discussed on _Meta_, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure name should end with `()` even if there is no `in` and `out` specified `update_counter()`

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_counter()
BEGIN 
 UPDATE bookmark bk,
 (SELECT count(Distinct user_bookmarks.user_id) AS bookmark_counter, bookmark_id 
  FROM user_bookmarks 
  LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON user_bookmarks.bookmark_id = bookmarks.id 
  GROUP BY user_bookmarks.bookmark_id 
 ) t
 set bk.counter = t.bookmark_counter
 where bk.id = t.bookmark_id;
END;//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: it works for me
Could you please explain END;// why you use ; after End

Comment: Well `;` does not need after `end` but adding is no harm, you can say its an old practice I have been doing for long :)

Comment: The best practice is you should always terminate each command with `;`, like the query in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the IN and OUT parameter in the header. If you do not have parameter, you have to add `()`

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_counter()
BEGIN 
 UPDATE bookmark bk,
 (SELECT count(Distinct user_bookmarks.user_id) AS bookmark_counter, bookmark_id 
  FROM user_bookmarks 
  LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON user_bookmarks.bookmark_id = bookmarks.id 
  GROUP BY user_bookmarks.bookmark_id 
 ) t
 set bk.counter = t.bookmark_counter
 where bk.id = t.bookmark_id;
END//

 delimiter;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END //' at line

Comment: @HituBansal You have to add `;` after `where bk.id = t.bookmark_id`

Comment: Still  error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 11

Comment: @HituBansal Remove the blank between `END` and  `//`

Comment: @HituBansal same line?

Comment: Yes same line , i above answer works for me, but i didt understand

Comment: i guess i missed delimiter; at last. do i need to use ?

Comment: @Hitu: it's worth considering answers on Stack Overflow as hints to get you on your way, not things that can be typed in verbatim without understanding them. If you get an answer that results in an error, play with it a bit, see _why_ you think it is not working. Here, I'd be inclined to put in a no-op update `UPDATE bookmark SET counter = 0 WHERE 1 = 0`, and then when the procedure compiles, swap it to the real thing. This will help you find whether the error is in the procedure or the update.